# Run .jar file on a PHP page

Tags: java, php, jar, exec, shell-exec

Good evening, I have a .jar file and I want it to be executed when the user accesses a specific php page on my website.

[Print of how I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aomgS.png)

I have already tried with exec and shell_exec but it is not returning anything (blank page loading). Do any of you know if there is a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share your PHP attempts as well as how their output failed so we can find the issue or attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'd like to see you run the Jar file on the command line by itself without the PHP.  Then we can verify that the Java program works.  Once Java works we can concentrate on getting it integrated with PHP.  If the Java isn't working then we should look at that instead.

Comment: Is the php running on a server and you expect the java to be run on the client's machine instead? If yes, is the java application already installed on their machine?

Comment: Open Web Start or IcedTea webstart is probably what you want

Comment: Jordan, here is the image of the lines of code and the output obtained by the browser through F12.
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tF9zGnb.png">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/HBVjihY.png">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2vsR9Z6.png">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/6YevVq6.png">

markspace, in the terminal it is running normally.
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/CzAsOto.png">

FedericoklezCulloca, yes, I have Java installed on my machine.

g00se, could you give me a tutorial on how to put your suggestions on my PHP page?

Comment: Please **do not** use images for code and logs. Use text. And don't add it in comments where it is hard to read. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute a jar file in the client computer of a web page because of security restrictions to avoid every computer in the world with a web browser to be hacked instanly.

You need to give the user instructions to install Java themselves in their computer, download the jar file and execute the application themselves.

There are toolkits like openwebstart.com that can help automate somewhat this but it may be overkill if your needs are simple.